# Reversing a string on C

Tags: c

I'm new in in code and I'm doing K&R for C coding, but I have some simple questions that are complicating me, I know it can be a very stupid question but again, I'm new and if you can explain me in a way that a noob would understand I will appreciate it.

Just want to store "4321" in srev[] but it just doesn't print anything, I know there is other ways to reverse a string but I would like to know why this one doesn't work, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXL 1000

char s[MAXL] = "1234"; 
char srev[MAXL]; 

main(){

    int i =0;                   
    for(i=0; 4>=i; ++i){  
        srev[i] = s[4-i];
    }

    printf("srev[]: %s", srev);
}
```

Comment: You forgot about the terminal zero

Comment: Related, `[c] reversing a string` in a search box on this site will return more similar questions with similar problems that you could probably read in a week.

Comment: `main()` is an invalid Signature in modern C. Never use it! And get a more recent book. K&R Rev 2 teaches ancient C, which is outdated since 17 years. If you learn K&R Rev 1: Instantly open the Window and throw it out!

Comment: And Yoda-conditions not using you should. Making unreadable your code they do.

Comment: I can't see why the question has been downvoted. To me it seems well formulated for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop the last thing you do is put `s[4]` into `srev[0]`. The that element (the fifth because arrays are zero indexed) is the strings null terminator. That means that the first thing in `srev` tells `printf` to stop printing.
Change your loop to this:

```
for(i=0; 3>=i; ++i){  
    srev[i] = s[3-i];
}
```

or:

```
for(i=0; 4 > i; ++i){  
    srev[i] = s[3-i];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon the comment by Dunno:  the string `"1234"`in C is five bytes long. The fifth byte `s[4]` is a zero byte denoting string termination.

Your code copies that zero byte to `srev[0]`, so now you have a C string that terminates before it has even begun.

Use `i<4` in your `for` loop (and adjust the arithmetic to `3-i` accordingly) so that you only swap the non-zero bytes. Then set `srev[4] = '\0';` explicitly to terminate the new string in the correct place.

Comment: `srev` is global, so it is already all `0`s. It doesn't hurt to explicitly set it though.

Answer (score 0):

becuase s[4] = '\0' which means end of character string. if you assign null terminator to a string it means you tell it: "it's the end, accept no more characters":

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXL 1000

char s[MAXL] = "1234"; 
char srev[MAXL]; 

main(){

    int i = 0;                   
    for(i=0; 4 > i; ++i){  
        srev[i] = s[3-i];  // 3 - 0 = 3 so s[3] = '4' s4 = '\0'
    }

    printf("srev[]: %s", srev);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```